# Does ActiveModel have a module that includes an "update_attributes" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I've set up an ActiveModel class in my Rails app like this:

```
class MyThingy
   extend ActiveModel::Naming
   extend ActiveModel::Translation
   include ActiveModel::Validations
   include ActiveModel::Conversion

   attr_accessor :username, :favorite_color, :stuff

   def initialize(params)
     #Set up stuff
   end

end
```

I really want to be able to do this:

```
thingy = MyThingy.new(params)
thingy.update_attributes(:favorite_color => :red, :stuff => 'other stuff')
```

I could just write update_attributes on my own, but I have a feeling it exists somewhere. Does it?

Answer (score 7):

No, but there's common pattern for this case:

```
class Customer
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

  attr_accessor :name, :credit_rating

  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :name, :credit_rating, :as => :admin

  def assign_attributes(values, options = {})
    sanitize_for_mass_assignment(values, options[:as]).each do |k, v|
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
end
```

It's [from here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) See the link for examples.

If you find yourself repeating this approach often, you can extract this method into a separate module and include include it on demand.

Comment: Are there any enlightenings for newer rails versions yet?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they pulled it out of active record and moved it to active model in Rails 5.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes

You should be able to include the module:

```
include ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment
```